# Adding new products to a store with a template, without changing other products in the store

Tags: product, magento-1.8, import, csv

I have recently taken over a store at work that I did not build, nor do I have enough experience with Magento to be truly confident yet.

I have a .csv product template, to add 195 new products to a new category with 4 subcategories I have already created in the back end, judging by the file, it is based around the SKU.

I am using `Magento 1.8.0.`

When checking the data before import, it says that there are 15 duplicate rows. Would that be related to the products already in the store?

In the template, it does not appear to be any duplicates in the SKU column. Could another column cause a duplicate problem? If I force the import, with it replace the older SKU, which I assume is one of the older products that is no longer being sold?

I looked into the data flow import, but it appears to replace the entire product catalog, which is definitely not what I would like to do.

I understand that these are quite introductory questions, but I can't afford to do mess up the whole store because of a lack of knowledge
I'm still new at this job and I really like it!

Comment: I'm not sure about `In the template, it does not appear to be any duplicates in the SKU column.`. Please, check again carefully.

Comment: When I check the data on the import panel, it says that there is duplicates with 15 rows, but then when I go to find any in the .csv document, none are found.

Comment: I think it was due to duplicate sku in your importing csv file.